# Calculate a counter in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to create a counter to track "likes" / "hearts" over a multimedia item displayed in my webpage most likely an image or a video, this functionality is pretty much standard and a very similar case to what facebook / Instagram / Dribble does.

I'd like some advice of how can I implement such kind of counter and I proceed with this implementation bearing in mind the best performance of it.

My entity model so far is the following:

```
public class Portfolio:Entity
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string FullSizeImage { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public MediaType MediaType { get; set; }
}
```

please take a look to a [dribbble](http://dribbble.com/?page=3) screenshot for reference
[image]

I'm using C# and MongoDB Driver / MongoRepository

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB supports atomic increment operations.  You can see the docs for this here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/inc/

```
db.portfolio.update({ _id: 10},{ $inc: { likes: 1 } });
```

This will update the likes field by 1 of the portfolio with an _id of 10.  Even if 2, or 10, different users do this at the same time, the increment operation will count them all.

In C#, there are a number of ways to do this, the easiest being to use the builders.

```
var query = Query<Portfolio>.EQ(x => x.UserId, 10);
var update = Update<Portfolio>.Inc(x => x.Likes, 1);

collection.Update(query, update);
```

Comment: What do you think about to have an array users ids per portfolio item and doing a count for the array ids? I remember that I read the count function doesn't perform well.